# Customized Login Response in Spring Security Basic Auth

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a table named "user_detail" having columns firstname,lastname,username,password.This table I am using for basic auth.

Currently when I give  username, password in the /login controller then it validates with the table data. I want first name to be returned on successful login.

Below is my code.

```
public class LoginController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/login")
    public LoginResponse login() {
        return new LoginResponse("You are authenticated");
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MongoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();


        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint).and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());



    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user-registration/users");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

public @Data class LoginResponse {

    private String message;

    public LoginResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}


@Component
public class MongoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("emailId").is(username));
        List<UserDetailData> user = mongoOperations.find(query, UserDetailData.class, "user_details");

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(user)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"));

        return new User(user.get(0).getEmailId(), user.get(0).getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```

Currently it returns "You are authenticated" instead of this I want the first name of the user from the DB for that username.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `http.successHandler(handler)`. In the most primitive case handler can extend `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class. This handler redirects user to an arbitrary url after authentication.

If firstname is fetched from DB, you can convey it with custom user object:

```
public class ExtendedUser extends User {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;
  private String name;

  ExtendedUser(String email, String password, boolean enabled,
                    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                    String name) {
      super(email, password, enabled, true, true, true, authorities);
      this.name = name;
  }
  // getter and setter
}
```

Then use this class in your UserDetailsService instead of plain 'User'. After that, in success handler you can retrieve it like `authentication.getPrincipal()` in `onAuthenticationSuccess` method. Then you can put it as a query parameter of redirect url

Comment: we can't do http.successHandler() for httpBasic().